# How to use static text instead of button in Matlab?

Tags: button, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm using GUIDE and having a really hard time stylizing pushbuttons.

Their backgrounds do not change despite repeated attempts through the properties inspector (only a thin border changes, not the entire pushbutton face).

I'm wondering if I could use static text instead of pushbuttons and what the best practice would be. Not sure if one should use `ButtonDownFcn` or `CreateFcn` and if it would be simply a matter of moving my lines of code under pushbutton callbacks to these new functions.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: For me (on r2013a) changing background color of `pushbutton` is effective, see [here](http://imgur.com/AZEQRWB)

Comment: thx @pooya this is very frustrating - I'm using R2013a on a Mac

Comment: I am on Windows. Can you try this and see if the same thing happens? `uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'Button', 'backgroundcolor', 'cyan')`. Also can you provide an image of the problem with pushbutton background color?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to implement the static text idea, but if you want to go back to your original pushbuttons and try styling them, the excellent Undocumented Matlab blog (no affiliation) has suggestions: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/button-customization/

Comment: There's also [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jtattoo-look-and-feel-demo) page that could be relevant.